# How to find the source css code when dev tools does not specify a file name?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome-devtools

I am making a website in wordpress and I'm using a paid template. The template comes with a bootstrap grid. The issue I have is editing some css code, because I can't find the source of the css codes. [image: Css codes]

As you can see on the screenshot, the media queries are located at `grid-responsive.css`. The code I want to edit is the css above it. I want to remove the `padding-right: 30px !important;` from `.mpce-prvt-4661-5a018ae17a157:not(.mpce-dsbl-padding-right)` and same for the left side.

**But** I can't find the css file and on the right side **it doesn't tell me which file the source is**. I searched in all the css files I have and couldn't find it. Someone having an idea how to locate it?

Comment: I know where `grid-responsive.css` is, it's about the css above it

Comment: My guess would be that it is dynamically generated from JS, so there is no CSS file to look in.

Comment: @idbruin: it seems to be a style inside `<style></style>` (generated by JS or included by any plugin?). Try to find string _30px !important_ in whole directory, you'll find where it's generated.

Comment: Press Ctrl-F and type `.mpce-prvt-4661-5a018ae17a157` it'll be an inline style

Comment: @panther if it is a inline style chrome would show the source anyway... Im not really sure if this happens with styles that are inserted via JS.

Comment: @panther wouldn't it be shown in `element.style` if it is inside a `<style></style>`? Maybe when it's generated by JS it doesn't

Comment: Thanks @Liam , I found it that way. It is in a `<style>` with id='template-name'-private-styles. So what @sébastien-gicquel is saying is the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your CSS in an other file. Usually, paid templates offer the possibility to add your own custom CSS in admin or in a custom CSS file. **Check your WordPress theme parameter or documentation**.

This method is called "override". It means that you don’t modify original template (otherwise your modifications could be deleted when you update the template).

You just copy and modify the CSS you want to change.

original CSS file :

```
.test {
    color: red;
}
```

In custom.css :

```
.test {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: @JohannesGrandy What do you mean ? I didn’t say that it had to be loaded async. `custom.css` has to be loaded after the original css file

Answer (score 0):

CSS references that do not show a source in the inspector are usually generated from sources that are not CSS.

The most common source for this is JavaScript.

The easiest solution would be to simply open the entire project in something like Visual Studio and search the whole project for the css string.

Comment: *The **easiest solution** would be to simply open the entire project in something like Visual Studio and search the whole project for the css string.* or press [Ctrl-F...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47325113/how-to-find-the-source-of-some-css-code?noredirect=1#comment81600929_47325113)